# Conditional rendering react js

Tags: reactjs

Ok, trying to render date from one component into a second component, but using conditional rendering so if date on component 1 is null, component 2 date field will not render. New to react. using following logic.

```
const enpDate = (earlyNotificationDate);
if (enpDate) {
    moment(earlyNotificationDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
}
```

Mentor does not like it and would rather wrap in function. Cannot get function to render properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary function `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false` like so

```
const component = ({ isNull}) => (
  <div>
    {isNull ? 
      (
        <Component1 />

      ) : (

        <Component2 />
      )}

  </div>
)
```