# Conditional rendering and executing on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, mui-datatable

I use Material Datatable in my React app and want to render the following part conditionally if `data` is not null or undefined. It is also ok for me not to execute `Object.entries(data).map(x => (` line.

```
<TableBody >
{
    Object.entries(data).map(x => (
      <TableRow key={x[0]}>
        <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[0]}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[1]}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))
}
</TableBody>
```

So, how can I do this properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional rendering react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743680/conditional-rendering-react-js)

Comment: `data && Object.entries(data).map(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two actions you can apply to render components under a condition.

1. `<expression> && <true>` In JS one quirky behaviour is that if `<expression>` evaluates to `true`, the second expression `<true>` is returned. You can make use of this if you just **don't want to render anything** if `<expression>` evaluates to `false`.
2. `<expression> ? <true> : <false>` This is useful if you want to **render something in any case**. This is called a ternary operator, nd you can think of it as an inline if-else statement that returns either the `<true>`- or the `<false>` expression, depending on what `<expression>` evaluates to.

Now, to check whether your data is valid or not, JS has another useful feature: **Truthy/falsy values**.
`""`*(empty string)*, `0`, `null`, `undefined` are coersed into the `false` value if used in a logical expression. So you can just check if data is valid by putting your `data` object into `<expression>`. And since this becomes a logical value, you can use the `!` in the beginning of the `<expression>` to toggle the values.

Some examples:

```js
{!data && <NoDataComponent /> /* Only renders if data is falsy */}
{data && <DataComponent /> /* Only renders if data is there */}

{data ? <DataComponent /> : <NoDataComponent /> /* Renders always one of the components but never both at the same time! */}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding && condition will handle null and undefined check for you

```
<TableBody >
{
  data && Object.entries(data).map(x => (
    <TableRow key={x[0]}>
      <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[0]}</TableCell>
      <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[1]}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
   ))
 }
 </TableBody>
```

If you want to write condition operator

```
<TableBody >
 {
  data ?  Object.entries(data).map(x => (
     <TableRow key={x[0]}>
      <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[0]}</TableCell>
      <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[1]}</TableCell>
     </TableRow>
   ))
   : null

 }
</TableBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just verify if data exists

```
{
 data ? 
 <TableBody >
    Object.entries(data).map(x => (
      <TableRow key={x[0]}>
        <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[0]}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="tableCell">{x[1]}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))
</TableBody>
: <h3>No hay data</h3>
}
```